# How to get multiple column-slices of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

for example,

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(1, 8), columns = list('abcdefgh'))
```

I want to select the columns 'b':'d' and 'f':'h', say both inclusive.

I know I could select 'b':'d' by executing:

`df2 = df.loc[:, 'b':'d']`, but something like `df2 = df.loc[:, ['b':'d', 'f':'h']]`
which is like the syntax in MATLAB wouldn't work here, so how can I select several
columns in dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concatenation of indices, but it works only with positions, so need [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) or [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html) + [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(8).reshape(1, 8), columns = list('abcdefgh'))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
0  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7

b = df.columns.get_loc('b')
d = df.columns.get_loc('d')
f = df.columns.get_loc('f')
h = df.columns.get_loc('h')
print (b,d,f,h)
1 3 5 7
```

```
b = df.columns.searchsorted('b')
d = df.columns.searchsorted('d')
f = df.columns.searchsorted('f')
h = df.columns.searchsorted('h')
print (b,d,f,h)
1 3 5 7

df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[b:c+1, f:h+1]]
print (df)
   b  c  d  f  g  h
0  1  2  3  5  6  7
```

It is same as:

```
df =  df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:4, 5:8]]
print (df)
   b  c  d  f  g  h
0  1  2  3  5  6  7
```

---

```
df =  df.iloc[:, np.r_['b':'d', 'f':'h']]
print (df)
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df =  df.loc[:,'b':'d'].join(df.loc[:,'f':'h'])
print (df)
   b  c  d  f  g  h
0  1  2  3  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do  this using pd.concat:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[:,'b':'d'],df.loc[:,'f':'h']],1)
Out[608]: 
   b  c  d  f  g  h
0  1  2  3  5  6  7
```

Answer (score 0):

One option for selecting multiple slices is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select_columns.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.select_columns(slice('b', 'd'), slice('f', 'h'))

   b  c  d  f  g  h
0  1  2  3  5  6  7
```

The caveat here is that you have to explicitly use python's builtin `slice`.